# IDs used in ARIA and labels must be unique

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a Form component that gets fields in props

```
  const loginFields = [
    { name: 'email', label: 'Email', type: 'email' },
    { name: 'password', label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
    { name: 'remember', label: 'Remember me', type: 'checkbox' },
  ];
```

And then in Form I map this array of fields but when I get to remember-me checkbox I want to render a bit different peace of code. So I decided to create two functions and based on field name render input or input-checkbox.

```
function createFormItem(field: Field) {
  return field.name === 'remember'
    ? createCheckboxField(field)
    : createInputField(field);
}
```

But then I started to get this error:

> IDs used in ARIA and labels must be unique: Document has multiple elements referenced with ARIA with the same id attribute: {expression}Microsoft Edge Tools axe/parsing.

in the function that's the first one in the code on input element.

```
  function createInputField(field: Field) {
    return (
      <div key={field.name}>
        <label
          htmlFor={field.name}
          className={`block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 ${
            errors[field.name] ? 'text-red-700' : ' '
          }`}
        >
          {field.label}
        </label>
        <input
          type={field.type}
          id={field.name}
          className={`appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 ${
            errors[field.name] ? 'border-red-300' : ' '
          }`}
          {...register(field.name, {
            required: 'This field is required.',
          })}
        />
        {errors[field.name] &&
          (typeof errors[field.name] === 'string' || 'message') && (
            <span className="font-medium text-red-500">
              {errors[field.name]?.message?.toString()}
            </span>
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

and here is another one for checkbox:

```
function createCheckboxField(field: Field) {
    return (
      <div key={field.name} className="flex items-center">
        <input
          type={field.type}
          id={field.name}
          className="h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500 border-gray-300 rounded"
          {...register(field.name)}
        />
        <label
          htmlFor={field.name}
          className="ml-2 block text-sm text-gray-900"
        >
          {field.label}
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I understand the error but it's like it doesn't know that I render those inputs conditionally so it throws an error. It doesn't even care about render, it just complains that I have two functions that return input which has id.

Changing ids to id={`'${field.name}-checkbox'`} and id={`'${field.name}-input'`} is not doing the trick.

And removing `{...register(field.name)}` from input is also doing nothing.

Here's my whole Form component:

```
const Form: FC<FormProps> = ({ fields, onSubmit, buttonLabel }) => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const handleFormSubmit = (formData: FormData) => {
    onSubmit(formData);
  };

  function createInputField(field: Field) {
    return (
      <div key={field.name}>
        <label
          htmlFor={field.name}
          className={`block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 ${
            errors[field.name] ? 'text-red-700' : ' '
          }`}
        >
          {field.label}
        </label>
        <input
          type={field.type}
          id={field.name}
          className={`appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 ${
            errors[field.name] ? 'border-red-300' : ' '
          }`}
          {...register(field.name, {
            required: 'This field is required.',
          })}
        />
        {errors[field.name] &&
          (typeof errors[field.name] === 'string' || 'message') && (
            <span className="font-medium text-red-500">
              {errors[field.name]?.message?.toString()}
            </span>
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  function createCheckboxField(field: Field) {
    return (
      <div key={field.name} className="flex items-center">
        <input
          type={field.type}
          id={field.name}
          className="h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500 border-gray-300 rounded"
          {...register(field.name)}
        />
        <label
          htmlFor={field.name}
          className="ml-2 block text-sm text-gray-900"
        >
          {field.label}
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function createFormItem(field: Field) {
    return field.name === 'remember'
      ? createCheckboxField(field)
      : createInputField(field);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleFormSubmit)} className="space-y-6">
      {fields.map(createFormItem)} 
      <div>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
        >
          {buttonLabel}
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
export default Form;
```

Comment: You may need a prefix on your `id` as these must be unique page-wide.

Comment: @tadman I did try it but like postfix '${field.name}-checkbox', even used useId